# Windows 2003 Permissions Problem

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, user-management, ntfs, file-permissions

I am trying to setup a new user on a Standalone (non-domain) Windows Server 2003 SP2.

The user needs FTP access to 1 folder in our web site's directory structure.

Here's exactly what I have done so far:

1. Created the new user in Computer Management.
2. Removed this new user from any groups.
3. In the security tab in the folder properties dialog (NTFS permissions) for the entire volume that holds our site, I explicitly denied full control access for this new user.
4. In the NTFS permissions for the folder that I wanted to GRANT access, I checked Allow Modify.
5. I logged in with the new users credentials from a remote FTP client.
6. I was able to read/write/modify/delete files and folders in the entire FTP structure, regardless of the deny permissions from #3 above.

Why is this happening?

Comment: did he inherit permissions from another directory in advanced permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Right click the folder in question and bring up the properties pages, select the security tab, click the Advanced button, select the Effective Permissions tab, browse for the user in question, this will show you what permissions the user has on the folder. From there you can troubleshoot where the permissions are "going wrong".

Comment: I have tried that as well, before posting. The effective permissions mirror the behavior of the ftp client (it tells me that the user has full rights, which I already knew.) I just can't pin down why.

Answer (score -1):

look at the chart and it will explain everything :)

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308419/en-us

What do you mean with grant access. I think you need to select Read & Write.

Greets
Stephan

Comment: Thanks, but I was aware of all of that. This isn't my first time working with NTFS permissions. I'm still having the problem.